# String from user input: replace commas with semicolons except those in quotations

Tags: replace, datatable, bluej

Hi i'm just learning programming using Bluej, the problem: from standard input, replace all commas with a semicolon except those commas which are inside double quotation marks.

example: "John, Smith" is here, able and ready, sometimes.

output : "John, Smith" is here; able and ready; sometimes.

Is there an easy way using .replace(',',';') except for the part of the string in quotations ("John, Smith")? or do i need something else?

Ok so i have tried this and i thought it was a good go, it compiles but result doesn't replace commas

```
import java.util.*;
public class CSVFile{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        input();
    }

    public static void input(){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String info;
        System.out.println("Enter Data");    //User inputs in CSV File format
        info = kb.nextLine();

        while (!info.equals("#")){
            process(info);
            System.out.println("Enter Data");
            info = kb.nextLine(); 
        }
        System.out.println("End of Program");
    }

    public static void process (String info){
        int sl, i, qCount;
        sl = info.length();
        qCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++){
            if (info.charAt(i)=='"'){
                qCount++;    //Quotation mark count                             
            }
            if (qCount%2 == 0 && info.charAt(i) == ',')    //if qCount remainder > 0 and info.charAt (i) == ','
            {
                info.replace(',',';');    //Replace commas with semicolons
            }
        }

        System.out.println(info+" "+qCount);
    }
}
```

Here i was trying to replace the info.charAt (i) if its a comma  but haven't got it right yet. Any suggestions?

Ok have tried a different approach and it works for the example.

```
   public static void process(String info){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(info);
        int n = str.length();
        int q = 1;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (str.charAt (i) == '"'){
                q++;
                j = q%2;                
            }
            if (str.charAt (i) == ',' && j > 0){
                str.setCharAt(i, ';');
            }
        }
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println("===================");
    }
```

can anyone suggest improvements? i learn better by example lol as you can tell if you go by how long it took me to come up with the answer. i can see how this would apply as if i had just opened a FileReader with a Scanner to read an actual CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took awhile, but i'm back again. The problem was

> 'replace all commas with a semicolon except those commas which are inside double quotation marks. //Closed quotes.

example: "John, Smith" is here, able and ready, sometimes.

output : "John, Smith" is here; able and ready; sometimes.

I tried lots of different codes with arrays and Lists and Maps but when it came down to it the answer was pretty simple lol I'd like to thank 'ddp' who asked this question " replace a character at a specific index in a string? " and 'Petar Ivanov' for his answer.

Here is the first try:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CSVFile{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        input();
    }

    public static void input(){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String info;
        System.out.println("Enter Data");    //User inputs in CSV File format
        info = kb.nextLine();

        while (!info.equals("#")){
            process(info);
            System.out.println("Enter Data");
            info = kb.nextLine(); 
        }
        System.out.println("End of Program");
    }

    public static void process (String info){
        int sl, i, qCount;
        sl = info.length();
        qCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++){
            if (info.charAt(i)=='"'){
                qCount++;    //Quotation mark count                             
            }
            if (qCount%2 == 0 && info.charAt(i) == ',')    //if qCount remainder > 0 and info.charAt (i) == ','
            {
                info.replace(',',';');    //Replace commas with semicolons
            }
        }

        System.out.println(info+" "+qCount);
    }
}
```

and it didn't work lol well it did the very first time but stopped working all together after about 3 goes. So i kept looking for solutions. And i found the solution provided by 'ddp' and 'Petar Ivanov'

in their example 'ddp' wanted to change a specific charAt (a specific index) and 'Petar' provided this example using a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder("domanokz");
myName.setCharAt(4, 'x');

System.out.println(myName);
```

so for my solution i made a the following process method and replaced the current process method.

```
public static void process(String info){
        StringBuilder info2 = new StringBuilder(info);
        int n = info2.length();
        int q = 1;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (info2.charAt (i) == '"'){
                q++;
                j = q%2;             //j is the remainder if q is an odd numder                
            }
            if (info2.charAt (i) == ',' && j > 0){
                info2.setCharAt(i, ';');
            }
        }
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(info2);
        System.out.println("===================");
    }
```

This only works as long as you beging the string with a quote mark and end the quotes otherwise it doesn't know what to do lol but it works on the examples i have which all begin with quote marks.

Any improvements on this would be very appreciated.